# Image dimension in yii framework

Tags: php, file-upload, yii

Is there any way to get image dimension (width, height) with upload image by:

```
CHtml::activeFileField(CModel $model, string $attribute, array $htmlOptions=array ( ))
```

and later with:

```
CUploadedFile getInstance(CModel $model, string $attribute)
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find any useful information [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile)

any ideas? Or should I use raw php methods?

Comment: You would need a image processing driver/library like http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/image to get dimensions for image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use native php function getimagesize(). 
In your case:

```
$imageInfo = getimagesize(CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'attributeName')->getTempName());
```

$image info variable returns array where 0 and 1 elements is width and height of the current image respectively

Comment: getInstance($model) or getInstance($model , 'field_name') ?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed this yesterday.

Just use this extension: [Image Yii Extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/image/)

Follow the instructions to installation and usage in the page.