# how to get image dimension from yii CUploadFile?

Tags: php, yii

i want to get image dimension like width and height from CUploadFile. i try to print image property using var_dump(). and here is my php code :

```
    $file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,$fieldname);
        $ekstension = strtolower($file->extensionName); //strtolower
        ;
        $size = $file->size;
        $type = $file->type;
        $imageinfo = getimagesize(CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,$fieldname)->getTempName());
        echo var_dump($imageinfo);
```

and here is array results

```
array(7) { [0]=> int(5120) [1]=> int(1440) [2]=> int(2) [3]=> string(26) "width="5120" height="1440"" ["bits"]=> int(8) ["channels"]=> int(3) ["mime"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" }
```

how i can print image width and height? thanks for your answer.

Comment: there's a `;` on line 3 with no reason.

Comment: This would help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208488/image-dimension-in-yii-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get width and height image like this :

```
    $image_width = $imageinfo [0];
    $image_height = $imageinfo [1];
```